# Django: dynamic IntegerField initial (renders empty)

Tags: django, forms

I need an integer form field to have a 'default' value. But I need to define this value at runtime.

I do it like ths:

```
# at my form constructor:
def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None, initial=None, error_class=ErrorList,
             label_suffix=':', empty_permitted=False):
    super(FlatSearchForm, self).__init__(data, files, auto_id, prefix, initial, error_class, label_suffix,
        empty_permitted)

    min_price = ... # some code to find the minimum price
    self.price_min = min_price # will be used later

    max_price = ... # some code to find the maximum price
    self.price_max = max_price

    # here we go:
    self.fields['price_from'] = forms.IntegerField(min_value=min_price, max_value=max_price, initial=min_price)
    self.fields['price_to'] = forms.IntegerField(min_value=min_price, max_value=max_price, initial=max_price)

# ...
# how I use the form (in views.py):
class SearchFlatView(ListView):
    model = Flat
    context_object_name = 'flats'
    template_name = 'catalog/search.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchFlatView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = FlatSearchForm(self.request.GET)
        return context
```

The problem is: values are not shown in the form when I render the field using {{form.price_from}} and {{form.price_to}} - these fields are just empty!

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How do you use the form? How do you instantiate it? Is it bound or unbound form?

Comment: updated the code. check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set dynamically initial values for fields in a bound form. See the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial

> The initial argument lets you specify the initial value to use when
>   rendering this Field in an unbound Form.

What you can do however is to create an unbound form, with still preserving the request.GET params:

```
initial = request.GET.copy()
initial['price_from'] = some_min_price
initial['price_to'] = some_max_price
context['form'] = FlatSearchForm(initial=initial)
```

While in the form __iniit__ you'll have:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    initial = kwargs.get("initial", {})
    default_min_value = ... #  some default value in case there is no `initial` passed
    default_max_value = ...
    self.fields['price_from'] = forms.IntegerField(min_value=initial.get('min_value', default_min_value), max_value=initial.get('max_value', default_max_value))
    self.fields['price_to'] = forms.IntegerField(min_value=initial.get('min_value', default_min_value), max_value=initial.get('max_value', default_max_value))
```

Or you may want to change this logic, if needed.